# Linker error when compiling STL container vector in Solaris Platform

Tags: c++, stl, solaris, stdvector

I am trying to use C++ STL container vector on a Solaris platform but I am unable to compile it successfully. I am getting the following error:

Undefined first referenced symbol in file
`void std::vector<int>::__insert_aux(int*,const int&)` iqdir_r_o/st_database.o
**ld: fatal**: symbol referencing errors.
 No output written to libiq16.so.1
**Error**:Link failed with exit code 512.

Here is the piece of code I have added:

```
void st_database::cpp_stl_vector_test(){
    std::cout << "Entering Vector Test\n";
    std::cout << "--------------------\n";
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(10);
    vec.push_back(20);
    std::cout << "Exiting Vector Test\n";
    std::cout << "-------------------\n";
}
```

I have also included the vector header file.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What linker? How do you build and link?

Comment: Compiler: CC: Sun C++ 5.11 SunOS_i386 2010/08/13
Linker: How do I identify the linker?
I am using my organization's internal build command.

Comment: Internally, this is being executed: CC -G -o libiq16.so.1 -h libiq16.so  -m64 -noex -z defs -Bsymbolic -xildoff  -Wl

Comment: Why are you using `-z defs` to build a shared object? Read the `ld` man page.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't know why those parameters are there. Also, this is the first time I am working with Solaris so I don't even know the meaning of each.

Comment: I also tried writing the same function in a standalone cpp program with `main` function and it compiled and executed successfully. Now, I have a doubt about what could be missing while working with the original code.

Comment: You need to learn the meaning of the arguments.  Read [the Solaris `ld` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/ld-1.html) and pay particular attention to the `-z defs` option.

Comment: IMO -z defs is a good thing as it forces undefined symbol detection at build time rather than at executable run time. But it does mean more work to keep the build working.